# Python - get all possible sums of elements inside n 1d arrays

Tags: python

Given an integer n, and an array a, I would like to return an array with all the possible values of sums of a with itself n times.

```
Example: n = 3, a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Output: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

First element is from 1+1+1, second is 1+1+2 etc.

Is there any elegant way to do that? I've tried loops, but since n isn't known in advance, I don't know how many loops I need to make.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generate all possible 3-element combinations, then sum them:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

n = 3
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print([sum(comb) for comb in combinations_with_replacement(li, n)])

# [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10, 11, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 9, 10, 11, 12, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Since you seem to be interested in the unique sums, use a set:

```
print(set(sum(comb) for comb in combinations_with_replacement(li, n)))

# {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
```

Note that there is no guarantee whatsoever that these will be ordered. If you want ordered output be explicit about it:

```
print(sorted(set(sum(comb) for comb in combinations_with_replacement(li, n))))
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you :) It won't let me accept the answer yet. I'll do it once I can

Comment: The author wishes for it to be irrespective of the value of `n`

Comment: @EthanKoch What do you mean? This question makes no sense without `n`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution could be to use `itertools.product`. Here you first generate pairs of 3 elements from `a` and then sum them. To get rid of the duplicates, you use set `{ }` and the summation is done usingn list comprehension. Here I am using `*[a]*n` to make it more general for any value of `n`.

```
import itertools
n = 3
totals = {sum(item) for item in itertools.product(*[a]*n)}
# {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
```

Another readable way to do it would be to use a variable `lists` and then pass it to `itertools.product`

```
lists = [a]*n
totals = {sum(item) for item in itertools.product(*lists)}
```

To get all the possible sums **including the duplicates**, simply use `[ ]` instead of `{ }`.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you and give you a set as the output to ensure unique sum values. `n` and `a` can be any integer or list, respectively.

```
import itertools

n = 3
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [a for _ in range(n)]
sums = set(sum(_b) for _b in itertools.product(*b))
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is equivalent to @Bazingaa's answer, yet is agnostic to `n`.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but just keep in mind that depending on `n` and the size of `a`, it is not very memory efficient

Comment: Thanks @DeepSpace -- noted for the future.

Answer (score 0):

A pure-Python implementation:

```
def comb_sum(arr, n):
    if n == 1:
        [(yield a) for a in arr]
    else:
        for i, a in enumerate(arr):
            [(yield a + b) for b in comb_sum(arr[i:], n-1)]

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n = 3
sums = set([c for c in comb_sum(my_list, n)])
```

Comment: Using a library (let alone a built-in module) ***does not*** render code to be "not-pure" python. If anything, ***not*** using built-in modules may be slower since the built-in modules are (most of the time) optimized by using efficient Python or in some cases by being implemented in C (which is inherently faster than Python).

Answer (score 0):

using `map` and `lambda`,

```
n = 3
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(list(set(map(lambda k:sum(k), combinations_with_replacement(a, n)))))
```